# Cargo logs get stuck after update to Cargo version 1.8.4

Tags: java, tomcat, cargo

after I updated Cargo from version 1.6.2 to the newest version (1.8.4) , Cargo logs seem stuck even if my server works perfectly fine.

```
===========================================================================================================================================

  ______      ___      .______        _______   ______       _______       ___       _______ .___  ___.   ______   .__   __.             
 /      |    /   \     |   _  \      /  _____| /  __  \     |       \     /   \     |   ____||   \/   |  /  __  \  |  \ |  |             
|  ,----'   /  ^  \    |  |_)  |    |  |  __  |  |  |  |    |  .--.  |   /  ^  \    |  |__   |  \  /  | |  |  |  | |   \|  |             
|  |       /  /_\  \   |      /     |  | |_ | |  |  |  |    |  |  |  |  /  /_\  \   |   __|  |  |\/|  | |  |  |  | |  . `  |             
|  `----. /  _____  \  |  |\  \----.|  |__| | |  `--'  |    |  '--'  | /  _____  \  |  |____ |  |  |  | |  `--'  | |  |\   |             
 \______|/__/     \__\ | _| `._____| \______|  \______/     |_______/ /__/     \__\ |_______||__|  |__|  \______/  |__| \__|             
                                                                                                                                         
 __       __  ____    ____  _______     __        ______     _______ ____    ____  __   _______ ____    __    ____  _______ .______      
|  |     |  | \   \  /   / |   ____|   |  |      /  __  \   /  _____|\   \  /   / |  | |   ____|\   \  /  \  /   / |   ____||   _  \     
|  |     |  |  \   \/   /  |  |__      |  |     |  |  |  | |  |  __   \   \/   /  |  | |  |__    \   \/    \/   /  |  |__   |  |_)  |    
|  |     |  |   \      /   |   __|     |  |     |  |  |  | |  | |_ |   \      /   |  | |   __|    \            /   |   __|  |      /     
|  `----.|  |    \    /    |  |____    |  `----.|  `--'  | |  |__| |    \    /    |  | |  |____    \    /\    /    |  |____ |  |\  \----.
|_______||__|     \__/     |_______|   |_______| \______/   \______|     \__/     |__| |_______|    \__/  \__/     |_______|| _| `._____|
                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                         
===========================================================================================================================================
DATE Fri Jan 22 12:09:45 CET 2021

[10:35:54.123][info][talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 8.x starting...
[10:35:54.209][warn][stalledLocalDeployer] The WAR contains a context.xml file which sets the path to [webapp], which means path set it the Cargo configuration will be ignored by Tomcat
[10:35:54.209][info][stalledLocalDeployer] Deploying [/home/myapp/.cargo/workspace/myapp/myapp-deployable-2.1.7-SNAPSHOT.war] to [/home/cactus/.cargo/configurations/myapp/webapps]...
[10:36:15.367][info][talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 8.x started on port [8080]
[10:35:44.120][info][talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 8.x is stopping...
[10:35:49.123][info][talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 8.x is stopped
```

In this example , my application is actually running even if it looks like it has been stopped. And there is a loading icon in the lowest part of the log.

Has anybody had experienced the same problem in the past?

Comment: Remark that the timestamps of the logs are not in chronological order. The messages saying that Tomcat is stopping should be the first ones. There is some race condition in Cargo.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I don't know the problem is a race condition , I will try to install a previous version of Cargo and see what happens. Thx

Comment: my guess is that everything works fine, but the log viewer reads the messages in sequential order and thinks that Tomcat hasn't started yet. Other software like Eclipse check if the Tomcat shutdown port is open: if you disable the port they panic.